# Group does and doesn't exist but can't be added because it exists

Tags: fedora, group

I'm trying to add my user to the `libvirt` group but I can't because it doesn't exist.

I also can't create the group because it does exist

```
[core@localhost ~]$ sudo usermod -a -G libvirt $(whoami)
usermod: group 'libvirt' does not exist
[core@localhost ~]$ sudo groupadd --system libvirt
groupadd: group 'libvirt' already exists
```

The group does not show up in `/etc/group` but it does show in `getent group`

What does this mean? Does the group exist or not? The OS is Fedora CoreOS.

Comment: Maybe you have other data sources /etc/nsswitch.conf.

Comment: Added excerpt from bug report with workaround hope this will help you out.  I know this isn't exactly what you where looking for but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug report on this issue https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1919994 hope this helps.

There is also reports of this issue on the Ubuntu forum and a couple other places so it doesn't look like your the only one having the problem.

EXCERPT FROM BUG REPORT:

Iker Pedrosa 2021-02-01 11:13:42 UTC
Apparently when installing the virt-manager package, libvirt group is added to /usr/lib/group file, instead of /etc/group. This isn't expected by shadow-utils, as it looks for the groups located in /etc/group file. I'll try to understand why this happens and how to fix it, but in the meantime I think I found a workaround. From a root shell (sudo su -) add the group information located in /usr/lib/group file to /etc/group by issuing "grep -E '^libvirt:' /usr/lib/group >> /etc/group". Now, you'll be able to add the user to the group with usermod.

The information was found in: https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/adding-user-to-a-group/12583/2

And this is the link for the Fedora Project where the issue was reported.

https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/adding-user-to-a-group/12583/6